# How do you access nested objects in Emberjs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to access a nested object from an ember model.
The models look like this:
Content:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  text: DS.attr('string'),
  createdBy: DS.attr('string'),
  status: DS.attr('string'),
  contentType: DS.attr('string'),
  author: DS.belongsTo('author', { embedded: true }),
  campaign: DS.belongsTo('campaign', { embedded: true })
});
```

Author:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Campaign:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I'm calling a list of objects from a Rails REST API. The data looks like this:

```
 {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "contents",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "The Great Escape",
        "text": "This is the way the world ends!",
        "status": "Draft",
        "content-type": "Blog Post",
        "created-by": "#\\u003cUser:0x007fe4920d8850\\u003e",
        "author": {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Daniel Duck",
          "created_at": "2017-10-17T21:56:00.105Z",
          "updated_at": "2017-10-17T21:56:00.105Z"
        },
        "campaign": {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Apple - Fall",
          "created_at": "2017-10-17T21:56:00.093Z",
          "updated_at": "2017-10-17T21:56:00.093Z"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "type": "contents",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Just a lonely Joe in search of his soul",
        "text": "One day he'll be a real boy.",
        "status": "Final",
        "content-type": "Email",
        "created-by": "#\\u003cUser:0x007fe4920d8850\\u003e",
        "author": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Roberta Rock",
          "created_at": "2017-10-17T21:56:00.103Z",
          "updated_at": "2017-10-17T21:56:00.103Z"
        },
        "campaign": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Blade Runner 2049",
          "created_at": "2017-10-17T21:56:00.091Z",
          "updated_at": "2017-10-17T21:56:00.091Z"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "type": "contents",
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Love in the time of Silicon Valley",
        "text": "Maybe love IS all we need.",
        "status": "Waiting for Review",
        "content-type": "PR Release",
        "created-by": "#\\u003cUser:0x007fe4920d8850\\u003e",
        "author": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "James Jackson",
          "created_at": "2017-10-17T21:56:00.101Z",
          "updated_at": "2017-10-17T21:56:00.101Z"
        },
        "campaign": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "PRP",
          "created_at": "2017-10-17T21:56:00.089Z",
          "updated_at": "2017-10-17T21:56:00.089Z"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I setup the contents route:

```
export default Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.get('store').findAll('content', {include: 'author'});
    }
});
```

I set up the template:

```
<div class="jumbo">
<h1>Contents</h1>

</div>
{{#each model as |content|}}
    {{content-listing content=content}}
{{/each}}
```

I set up the listing component like this:

```
{{yield}}
<article class="content">
  <h3>{{content.title}}</h3>
  <div class="detail owner">
    <span>Author:</span> {{content.author}}
  </div>
  <div class="detail text">
    <span>Text:</span> {{content.text}}
  </div>
  <div class="detail status">
    <span>Status:</span> {{content.status}}
  </div>
  <div class="detail content_type">
    <span>Content Type:</span> {{content.contentType}}
  </div>
</article>
```

When I try to list the objects:

```
Contents

The Great Escape

Author: <DS.PromiseObject:ember389>
Text: This is the way the world ends!
Status: Draft
Content Type: Blog Post
Just a lonely Joe in search of his soul

Author: <DS.PromiseObject:ember392>
Text: One day he'll be a real boy.
Status: Final
Content Type: Email
Love in the time of Silicon Valley

Author: <DS.PromiseObject:ember395>
Text: Maybe love IS all we need.
Status: Waiting for Review
Content Type: PR Release
```

How do I resolves the Promise and get the author object?

Comment: I'm assuming that your response is not properly formatted, I think that author should be under "relationships" key not under "attributes". So that may confuse ember-data.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the response, `content.author` is an object

```
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "James Jackson",
      "created_at": "2017-10-17T21:56:00.101Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-10-17T21:56:00.101Z"
    }
```

Try changing the `hbs` to be `content.author.name`

Comment: I tried that.  It used to throw an error.  Now it doesn't show anything.  Somehow that promise needs to get resolved, just not sure how to do it. :/